Keycode for copy/paste/cut
I wanted to use keyd to map some keys to copy/paste/cut in a layout-independent way, and I saw some keyboards (typematrix) that have keys for copy/paste… But unfortunately, I can't find any keycode to do that, how can these keyboards work?

It seems like there is no keycode for this, but Linux & Windows (not sure about Mac, but people reported in 2021 that KeyRemap4MacBook can be used to do that by clicking on Change key > Use PC Style Copy/Paste) agreed on the fact that:

Copy is Ctrl + insert
Cut is Shift + Del
Paste is Shift + insert

See also this discussion https://groups.google.com/g/typematrix-user-group/c/Djo1CZAt99I, they also discuss HID.
